# In which O-class does my Θ-result belong?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

In a multiple-choice test, I'm asked to solve the recurrence $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n/2$.
I've done this using the master theorem: $f(n)=n/2$, $a=2$, $b=2$, so we're in the second case and $T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

But the possible answers are $O(\log n)$, $O(n)$, $O(n \log n)$, $O(n^2)$ and $O(n^2/\log n)$ and more than one may be correct. What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've solved the recurrence more precisely than the test-setter was expecting you to.  You know that $T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$, which means that $T(n) = O(n\log n)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(n\log n)$, and that gives you the answer.

(By the way, I didn't check that you solved the recurrence correctly, but you can do that yourself. Answer checking is off-topic here, and you didn't ask for it, so I focused on the rest of your question.)

Comment: (sound of screeching breaks) You called?

Comment: I'd say there are three correct answers, and I'd definitely mark all of them. To be fair, we don't know that the author wrote "there is exactly one correct answer"; Mike may be expected to cross all correct answers, in which case the question makes perfect sense (as far as MC questions go).

Comment: @Raphael Can't you at least find a technicality to arrest him on?

Comment: Yes, suspect just  confirmed there could be more than one correct answer

Comment: @MikeRed OK, false alarm. Move along everybody. Nothing to see here. Nothing to see. Move along, please!

Comment: Next time, then. ($\Theta$-club and $\sim$-cuffs go back into the trunk.)